# What would be needed beat and synthesis wise in order to make something like this?

Tags: jazz

I'm really concerned on how they did the piano and clarinet echo (if that's even what it is), because I've been looking for tutorials on YouTube for stuff like how to make a "boombape type beat" or "lofi beat" but nothing came close enough to show what I'm looking for. I'm not trying to duplicate this person's beat in anyway, just curious on how and what was used to make it educationally. Thank you

(Devaloop - Nightshift (Instrumental))

Answer (score 2):

The most common way to put together a piece of music like this is to simply take samples / recordings of musicians playing appropriate beats and phrases, and loop and trigger portions of those samples to make a new beat with a new feel. These days there are probably many types of products that you could use to do this, and thousands of individual products that have these capabilities. Looking back into hip-hop history, one noteable series of machine that was often used to make this kind of beat was the Akai MPC series, starting with the MPC60 in 1988. The audio technology used was much better than what was possible using most home computers at the time, but was still basic by today's standards (12-bit sampling at 40KHz) - that, in combination with the scratchy audio quality obtained by sampling from old vinyl records, is the kind of thing gives lo-fi beats their characteristic sound. Another aspect of the 'lo-fi' feel comes from drum beats with one rhythmic feel being forced into a slightly different feel.

MPC machines are still available today, as are many similar devices. but so is the possibility of doing this kind of sample manipulation in a DAW (digital audio workstation), or even using an audio programming language.

Likewise with the delay effect there is no one particular piece of equipment you need. Tape delay effects are often associated with lo-fi style production, and of course there are now many virtual tape delays available.

Of course it would also be possible to synthesize a piece like this without using samples of musicians playing - but starting by following something like the original process of sampling sections of music and retriggering them will help you understand where much of the characteristic sound comes from.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a program to do this:
what you can hear is just the basic rhythm of a drum pattern (except of the fill ins at the breaks).
but the base drum is not on 1 and 3 as it is placed 1 and 3 +! that means there may be also played to eight notes on beat 3 but the first one is muted and the accent is on the second eight note.  that makes it more interesting to listen at.
[image]

to perform this you can use any sequencer program ... there are lots of free downloads here.

Comment: In electronic music genres, often the notes as such are not enough. You need very specific sounds, very specific effects, timbres, waveforms, to even get  categorized in the whole genre. There's no way to explain e.g. how to create a "lo-fi beat" using traditional musical notation, just as there's no way to describe how to do the autotune effect, using musical notation. I think the OP is asking for very specific effects and settings, plugin brands and models, sample libraries. "What products to buy, which buttons to press." That's how music is made nowadays. ;)

Comment: Hey,  I have the complete vst libraries  of dorico, halion, iconica 
https://www.steinberg.net/de/products/vst/iconica/sections_and_players.html
and note performer. The trouble is I don't know where the bug is while the audio driver doesn't work: is it my laptop, is it windows 10 or is it the licence key of Halion SE and Cubase V. The Steinberg production had always problems with their software. I used already in 1988 their  twenty four sequencer and master score with Atari ST1024. It was a agony. But note performer by wallander instruments works with Finale.
https://www.noteperformer.com/

Comment: I don't know what this has to do with the question, but I highly recommend Steinberg's UR series of USB audio interfaces. I have UR44 and UR22mkII, and they are incredibly solid and well-working, works in Windows, Mac, Linux and iOS. *All* my audio interface related problems went away after switching from Echo to Steinberg. All of it, from analog Hi-Z input quality to software drivers, solid low latency, everything totally solved. DAW related frustration went away by switching from Cubase to Ableton Live over a decade ago. My first MIDI sequencer program was Cakewalk for DOS in 1989. :)